# 18.04: Gigabyte Aero 15x, laptop charger detected but battery not charging

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery

I successfully installed Ubuntu 18 in a new Gigabyte Aero 15x laptop. Everything's working fine, except for the battery.

If I turn on the laptop with the charger connected, then no problem, Ubuntu gets it and understands when the battery's fully charged.

However, if I turn on the laptop without the charger connected and later connect the charger, it won't be recognised, and the only way to make it charge again will be to shut down and restart the system, this time with the charger connected.

This never happened with other older laptops. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 18 (*there is no Ubuntu 18*) is usually used on appliances with permanent power connection so may not have the laptop software found on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for desktops, but I don't think it'll matter as charging of batteries is usually handled by hardware itself, with the OS playing no part (except indicators for the users of events happening on screen display; but Ubuntu Core 18 was intended for use on headless appliances)

Comment: @guiverc, sorry I didn't specify the exact version I'm using, thought adding LTS would be enough. This error is happening on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for desktop. And yes, the hardware reacts properly - this laptop has a small led which indicates when the power cord is connected. But even if this led works ok, Ubuntu still shows the battery being drained.

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu Core 18 is an LTS too.  I don't know enough about charging indicators used in the GNOME desktop, but on some testing I did during the 18.10 cycle, I did note some delays on notifications on battery indicators being displayed (on events like charger plugged in, removed, battery % life changes etc). I can't recall the specifics, I did the testing, reported my findings in pad.ubuntu.com & forgot it. In no test was the battery charging, draining impacted by the OS, just indicators were slow to appear on screen showing changes in some cases, but that was three releases or too long ago.